# iis7 url rewrite for webforms aspx to mvc page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, iis-7, url-rewrite-module

I have had a website with `/contact.aspx` which gets a succesful redirect to `/contact`
But I want to redirect my old `/content.aspx?contentid=123` to `/about/123`
Here is my redirect XML part in my web.config:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="contact" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="contact.aspx" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="Contact" redirectType="Found" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Content" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="content.aspx?contentID=*" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="About/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Visiting mydomain.com/content.aspx?contentid=123 gives me a 404.
also tried without `appendQueryString="false"`
Seems easy to fix to me, but I am missing something...

using a regex instead of wildcard also gives a 404:

```
<rule name="Content">
    <match url="content.aspx?contentID=([0-9]+)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="About/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [IIS rewrite module configuration documentation.](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference)

> The URL string that is evaluated against the pattern does not include the query string. To include the query string in the rule evaluation you can use the QUERY_STRING server variable in the rule’s condition.

So after a big of test jiggery-pokery, I think this should work:

```
<rule name="Content" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="content.aspx" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="contentID=([^&amp;]+)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="About/{C:1}" redirectType="Found" appendQueryString="False" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Seems almost right. I got: Error?aspxerrorpath=/About/192 when About/192 does work.

Comment: Hmm... I can't think why but there must be some difference. It sounds like you have custom errors on, can you turn them off to see an actual error page instead?