# How do I Redirect page.ASPX to / in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have rewritten our app in MVC5 and there is a new homepage "http://server/".

People have bookmarked our old homepage "http://server/App.aspx" and their links are now broken.

What do I do to redirect "http://server/App.aspx" to "http://server/"

TIA!

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31589259/iis7-url-rewrite-for-webforms-aspx-to-mvc-page) it might be of some use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the IIS rewrite module if it installed. All you need to do is add this to the `system.webServer` node in the web.config.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="rule1" stopProcessing = "true" >
      <match url="App.aspx" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```